# How to use Android Browser class(for Bookmark)

Tags: android, browser, bookmarks

I want to make App for bookmark.
I already have searched site about this question.
but it is not enough and detail.
how can I do?
I knew I have to using Browser class but that don't has many data.
I ask to Browser class's example sources or detail tips for making bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
saveBookmark(Context c, String title, String url)
```

Please refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Browser.html#saveBookmark(android.content.Context,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

For Context parameter you can pass `MainActivity.this` only if your
`MainActivity extends Activity` then other two parameters are self explanatory.

In your AndroidManifest.xml add the following code

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
```

If you have any doubts feel free to comment @user1063231